# Injeção de dependências em funções e não classes. É "errado"?

Tags: typescript, design-pattern, estilo-de-codificação, injeção-de-dependência, ioc

Não é novidade que o conceito de injeção de dependências está quase que diretamente relacionado a classes. Diga-me "injeção de dependências" e eu já imagino o seguinte:

```
// services/UserService.ts

export default class UserService {
  constructor(
    private manager: DatabaseManager
  ) {}

  async createUser(username: string, password: string): User {
    const user = new User();
    user.username = username;
    user.password = password;

    await this.manager.save(user);
    return user;
  }
}
```

Agora gostaria de saber se esses mesmos conceitos podem ser aplicados em uma função sem prejudicar o "estilo" funcional.

Pensei em implementar o meu próprio *container* de dependências e utilizá-lo de forma similar aos React Hooks:

```
// services/create-user.ts

export default async function createUser(username: string, password: string): User {
  const [manager] = useContainer([DatabaseManager]);

  const user = new User();
  user.username = username;
  user.password = password;

  await manager.save(user);
  return user;
}
```

Eu sei que posso implementar isso e irá funcionar. O objetivo dessa pergunta é saber se estarei ferindo algum princípio da injeção de dependência (ou das próprias funções) ao fazê-lo. Seria um erro fazer isso?

Comment: O que é esse `useContainer()`?

Comment: Seria uma função cujo objetivo seria recuperar alguma coisa do IoC container. Mais tarde edito a pergunta para deixar isso mais claro...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pra mim a foma como deseja fazer é injeção de dependência *done right*. O que eu não gosto é de penduricalho pra fazer algo simples. Criar parâmetro na função ou campo em classe com o único objetivo ter flexibilidade da dependência me parece muito errado.

Em muitos casos sequer deveria ter a flexibilidade, mesmo onde deve ter, deveria ser transparente para a aplicação.

Não sei bem como funciona esse mecanismo usado na pergunta, mas pra mim parece correto, mesmo que ele não siga a filosofia da DI (eu não me apego a regras, me apego a soluções) você cria uma forma de pegar a informação que precisa a hora que precisa, se essa forma é flexível ou não é problema dela e não do seu uso aí (desacoplamento), eu faria desta forma e nunca da que muita gente faz criando custo para o objeto. A não ser que tenha um objetivo maior de ter um controle na classe, mas não parece ser o caso.